# Deleting comments from file

Tags: c

I have a task: delete all comments from a file and save the result to a new file. it should be taken into account that comments can be inside double quotes (then they do not need to be deleted) and do not forget about transferring the comment to a new line. I managed to meet all the requirements, except for the line break. how can I do this? maybe I have a mistake somewhere?

**that's what I did:**

```
char c, nextChar;
int insideComment = 0;
int insideQuotes = 0;
int ignoreNewline = 0;
while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
    if (!insideComment) {
        if (c == '/') {
            nextChar = fgetc(input);
            if (nextChar == '/') {
                if (!insideQuotes) {
                    while ((c = fgetc(input)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
                } else {
                    fputc(c, output);
                    fputc(nextChar, output);
                }
            } else if (nextChar == '*') {
                if (!insideQuotes) {
                    insideComment = 1;
                } else {
                    fputc(c, output);
                    fputc(nextChar, output);
                }
            } else if (nextChar == '\\') {
                while ((c = fgetc(input)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
                    //what should I write here?
                }
            } else {
                if (insideQuotes) {
                    fputc(c, output);
                    fputc(nextChar, output);
                } else {
                    fputc(c, output);
                    fputc(nextChar, output);
                }
            }
        } else if (c == '\"') {
            insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
            fputc(c, output);
        } else {
            fputc(c, output);
        }
    } else {
        if (c == '*' && (nextChar = fgetc(input)) == '/') {
            insideComment = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**input file:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!");
    //i'm comment;
    /*i'm comment too*/
    /*and i'm multiline 
comment*/

    // hello hello \
hello hello hello hello hello



    printf(" //here is quotes");
    return 0;
}
```

**expected output:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!");
        
    




    printf(" //here is quotes");
    return 0;
}
```

**what i get:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!");
        
    

    hello hello hello hello hello



    printf(" //here is quotes");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very important note: [The `fgetc` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`**. Which is important when comparing to the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: You also need to handle invalid files, like one ending with a single `/`. You don't really check the result of the second `fgetc` inside the loop.

Comment: Regarding line-continuation, you need to treat any line with a line-continuation as one single line. So if a comment-line ends with a line-continuation, you need to treat the rest of the current line *and* the next line as a single comment. And be ready to handle another line-continuation on that next line as well.

Comment: A backslash effects a line continuation only if the character immediately following is a newline. Therefore, when you are processing a `'\\'`, you should read the next character to check whether it is a newline. If not, then just `ungetc()` the non-newline and process the backslash as an ordinary character.

Comment: Handling the full generality of C comments is an irksome business.  It is about to get more complex because in C23 you can have numbers like `0b0101'1101` (and `0xABCD'EF01'2345'6789`) with an odd number of single quotes not forming a quoted character.  That's been a feature in C++ for a few years now.  You can have an arbitrary number of backslash-newline pairs between the `/` and the `*` that open a comment and between the `*` and `/` that end a comment, and between the two slashes at the start of a `//` comment, and a `//` comment can be continued over multiple lines with a backslash.

Comment: If the next character *is* a newline then your job is more complicated. Supposing that the file must remain absolutely unchanged except for comment removal, you have to watch out for these things: the opening `/*`, opening `//`, or closing `*/` of a comment is split by one or more backslash/newline pairs, or a `//` comment is split across multiple lines by one or more backslash / newline pairs.  Line continuations inside the bodies of block comments will be removed either way. But you must *avoid* processing line continuations that appear elsewhere.

Comment: Note that none of these lines contains a comment: `long c = '/*';` — `long d = '*/';` — `long e = '//';` — `puts("\"/* Not a comment */\"");` — `puts("\"// Not a comment\"");`. None of these involves a backslash-newline sequence.  Multi-character character constants exist but are non-portable — [_implementation defined_](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p10) in the jargon.  You will need to handle them.  You can probably afford to ignore trigraphs, mercifully, and digraphs do not affect comment processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing out your code, with the addition of needed code for a "main" function and file descriptors, I also encountered the same issue with the "hello hello hello hello hello" text being copied to the scrubbed output file.  In debugging the code, the issue mainly resided within the block of code dealing with the next character being equal to `"\\"`.

```
        nextChar = fgetc(input);
        if (nextChar == '/') {
            if (!insideQuotes) {
                while ((c = fgetc(input)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
            } else {
                fputc(c, output);
                fputc(nextChar, output);
            }
```

Instead of attempting to condense all of the testing into a single "if" statement, I found that there needed to be additional testing and usage of the "ignoreNewline" flag regarding subsequent ignoring of comment characters.  With that said, the following is a refactored version of your code with an expanded set of tests within that "if" test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    FILE *input, *output;

    char c, nextChar;

    int insideComment = 0;
    int insideQuotes  = 0;
    int ignoreNewline = 0;

    input  = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    output = fopen("scrubbed.txt", "w+");

    while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
    {
        if (!insideComment)
        {
            if (c == '/')
            {
                nextChar = fgetc(input);
                if (nextChar == '/')
                {
                    if (!insideQuotes)
                    {
                        while(1)
                        {
                            c = fgetc(input);                   /* Get the next character   */

                            if (c == EOF)
                                break;

                            if (c == '\\')                      /* If the new line continuation character is sensed, ignore the subsequent newline */
                                ignoreNewline = 1;

                            if (ignoreNewline == 1 && c == '\n')
                            {
                                ignoreNewline = 0;              /* Once the subsequent newline character is reached, then reset the new line continuation flag */
                                continue;
                            }

                            if (c == '\n')                      /* If this point is reached, then the end of the comment(s) should have been reached */
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fputc(c, output);
                        fputc(nextChar, output);
                    }
                }
                else if (nextChar == '*')
                {
                    if (!insideQuotes)
                    {
                        insideComment = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fputc(c, output);
                        fputc(nextChar, output);
                    }
                }
                else if (nextChar == '\\')
                {
                        //what should I write here? /* This "else/if text won't be needed due to the above added logic  */
                }
                else
                {
                    if (insideQuotes)
                    {
                        fputc(c, output);
                        fputc(nextChar, output);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fputc(c, output);
                        fputc(nextChar, output);
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (c == '\"')
            {
                insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
                fputc(c, output);
            }
            else
            {
                fputc(c, output);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (c == '*' && (nextChar = fgetc(input)) == '/')
            {
                insideComment = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Following are the key points.

- Since various testing of characters would be needed, the character retrieval using "fgetc" was isolated.
- The setting of the "ignoreNewline" flag was then set based upon the character found.
- Subsequently, if a "newline" character was read, it was ignored if the flag was set, but this then triggered a reset of the flag.
- Performing these tests within this code block removed the need of the "else/if" block farther along where you ask "what should I write here".

Running this refactored code produced the following output data in the scrubbed file, which appears to be the desired result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!");
        
    

    


    printf(" //here is quotes");
    return 0;
}
```

This code refactoring also takes into account the good comments that have been submitted.

Give that a go to see if it meets your requirements.  Also, it might be beneficial to reference come more tutorial literature as it pertains to usage of "while" loops with the usage of "continue" and "break" statements.

Comment: `char c; ... while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF)` does not well handle the 257 different return vlaues of `fgetc()`.  Better with `int c;`.